# side scan sonar

Tags: ros, sonar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm working on an underwater robot simulator.
The dynamic and control parts are covered and I am now trying to simulate side-scan sonars, as it is a commonly used sensor in AUV.
Are there any ROS packages that already simulate this kind of sensors?
I found a few papers on the theory, but nothing usable without recoding all the ray tracing.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/149711/side-scan-sonar/) by [Olivier Kermorgant](https://answers.ros.org/users/11856/olivier-kermorgant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 280 on 2014-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Generation of this kind of sensor data has to be performed inside the simulator, so I´m not sure how a existing ROS package could help you there. Gazebo provides a [RaySensor](http://gazebosim.org/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1sensors_1_1RaySensor.html) that can be used inside plugins to generate simulated sensor data for your ROS robot, but as you are working on your own simulator this probably can only serve as inspiration.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Olivier Kermorgant](https://answers.ros.org/users/11856/olivier-kermorgant/) on 2014-04-09**:
Yep, I'm actually using Gazebo, just added buoyancy and other hydro effects to deal with the underwater environment. I'll look into this RaySensor as a base for a sidescan sonar plugin.
Thanks!